# Lightning Runtime Flow URL retURL to any page on salesforce is broken because of CORS

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, cors

CORS Error:
CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Access at XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain-dev-ed--c.na94.visual.force.com'
from origin 'https://domain-dev-ed--namespace.na94.visual.force.com' has been blocked because of CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've added both domains as CORS Whitelists in setup. Get this error whether attempting to navigate to a visualforce page or a standard page like 'home/home.jsp'.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Enable Lightning Run time for flows in process automation settings.
- Open the flow in a new window and set `retURL=home/home.jsp` should navigate you to the home page.

Full url: `/flow/flowName?retURL=home/home.jsp`

When you turn off Enable Lightning runtime for flows, it works ....

## Edit

- Looks like its a issue with namespaced orgs